# Tensor independence

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $(e_{i})$ be a basis in $V$, $( \epsilon_{i} )$ - basis in $V^{*}$ so that $\epsilon_{i} (e_{j})= \delta_{i}^{j}$ (Kronecker delta, $\epsilon_{i} (e_{j}) =  1 \Leftrightarrow i=j$, otherwise it's equal to $0$.)

$u = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{e_{k} \otimes \epsilon_{k}} \in V \otimes V^{*}$. How to prove that $u$ does not depend on the basis choice in $V$?

It's reasonable to take into account that $V \otimes V^{*} \simeq Hom(V, V)$, where the isomorphism is $(v, \alpha) \mapsto \alpha(x) \cdot v$ but i had some troubles interpreting $u$ in terms of $Hom(V, V)$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The element $u$ corresponds to $\mathrm{id}_V$ of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm
That clarifies everyting. Thanks.